# At what dataset size does Orange performance begin to get impacted?

Tags: orange

I can't find any information on max size for data uploaded to Orange before it starts to get bogged down. This information would be helpful to know so that I can minimize how much I need to sample.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Do you mean performance like memory and CPU, or performance like evaluation measure? For the former the limit likely depends on the particular computer being used. For the latter, there's no general answer to this question, it completely depends on the data: how noisy it is, whether the features are good indicators, etc.

Comment: @Erwan that is a fair point regarding performance, and that is what I meant by in my question. I guess my follow up then would be how I can go about figuring my upper limits given my memory and CPU?

Comment: Honestly I think the only way is by trial and error with a particular dataset,